# How do I access a legacy Mathematica CDF?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, enterprise, cdf

I have a CDF Notebook written on an Enterprise version of Mathematica 11, so anyone should be able to download a CDF reader and use the notebook. When I search for a CDF reader, however, the one that comes up is for a legacy version of Windows:

[image]

Where can I find an updated CDF reader or how can I access the notebook?

Comment: It's called Wolfram Player now. https://www.wolfram.com/player/

Answer (score 0):

From the Wolfram site:

> [Computable Document Format (CDF)](https://www.wolfram.com/cdf/) is a legacy document type.
> Interact with existing CDF files using [Wolfram Player](https://www.wolfram.com/player/).